# Converting outer apply with Correlated subquery in SQL Server to SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I need to convert a query in SQL Server to SQlite and I have replaced the outer apply to left outer join, but how to limit the subquery to return only 1 in this situation?  And how to pass the reference value from outer table into sub query?

I have highlight the things that i am not able to convert it into Sqlite, can anybody please give some advise ?

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.CodeValue ,
        a.TotalAmount ,
        InvoiceRevised.RevisedInvoiceId,
        InvoiceRevised.BillNumber AS RevisedInvoice,
        patientlookup.RegistrationNumber AS RegistrationNumber,
        patientlookup.PatientName AS PatientName,
FROM dbo.Invoices a
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Invoices.Id AS RevisedInvoiceId,CodeValue AS InvoiceNumber,
    dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.CreatedOn AS InvoiceTime,
    dbo.Invoices.CreatedBy AS InvoiceCreatedBy,
    dbo.Invoices.TotalAmount,dbo.Invoices.Discount,
    dbo.Invoices.RoundAmount 
    FROM Invoices 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SCSInvoiceRels ON dbo.Invoices.Id = dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.InvoiceId 
        AND dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.RecordStatus = 1 AND dbo.Invoices.RecordStatus = 1 AND  dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.SCDetailId IN (
            SELECT SCDetailId FROM dbo.SCSInvoiceRels WHERE InvoiceId = a.id)
) InvoiceRevised
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 pr.CodeValue AS RegistrationNumber,pa.Name AS PatientName FROM dbo.PatientRegs pr 
INNER JOIN dbo.Patients pa ON pa.id = pr.PatientId
INNER JOIN dbo.SCDetails SC ON pr.id = SC.RegId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SCSInvoiceRels SCb ON SC.id = SCb.SCDetailId
WHERE SCb.InvoiceId = a.Id
) patientlookup
WHERE RecordStatus = 0 AND  UpdateOn IS NOT NULL
```

**SQLite:**

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.CodeValue ,
        a.TotalAmount ,
        InvoiceRevised.RevisedInvoiceId,
        InvoiceRevised.BillNumber AS RevisedInvoice,
        patientlookup.RegistrationNumber AS RegistrationNumber,
        patientlookup.PatientName AS PatientName,
FROM dbo.Invoices a
Left outer join (
SELECT dbo.Invoices.Id AS RevisedInvoiceId,CodeValue AS InvoiceNumber,
    dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.CreatedOn AS InvoiceTime,
    dbo.Invoices.CreatedBy AS InvoiceCreatedBy, 
    dbo.Invoices.TotalAmount,dbo.Invoices.Discount,
    dbo.Invoices.RoundAmount 
    FROM Invoices 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SCSInvoiceRels ON dbo.Invoices.Id = dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.InvoiceId 
        AND dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.RecordStatus = 1 AND dbo.Invoices.RecordStatus = 1 AND  dbo.SCSInvoiceRels.SCDetailId IN (
            SELECT SCDetailId FROM dbo.SCSInvoiceRels WHERE InvoiceId = a.id)
) InvoiceRevised
Left outer join(
SELECT pr.CodeValue AS RegistrationNumber,
       pa.Name AS PatientName,
       SCb.InvoiceId as InvoiceId 
FROM dbo.PatientRegs pr 
INNER JOIN dbo.Patients pa ON pa.id = pr.PatientId
INNER JOIN dbo.SCDetails SC ON pr.id = SC.RegId 
INNER JOIN dbo.SCSInvoiceRels SCb ON SC.id = SCb.SCDetailId
) patientlookup on patientlookup.InvoiceId = a.Id
WHERE RecordStatus = 0 AND  UpdateOn IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 12):

SQLite does not support lateral or correlated joins.  You can work around that using a join condition.  For example:

```
create table t1 (id int, name text);
create table t2 (id int, t1id int references t1(id), name text);
insert into t1 values (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
insert into t2 values (1, 1, 'a1'), (2, 1, 'a2'), (3, 2, 'b1');
```

Now we'd like to look up at most one row from `t2`, sorted by `name`.  Here's one approach that will work in SQLite:

```
select  *
from    t1
left join
        t2
on      t2.id =
        (
        select  id
        from    t2
        where   t1.id = t2.t1id
        order by
                name desc
        limit   1
        )
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/291a1/1)

Comment: it's very simple and useful.. and perfectly working.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

To limit the number of rows returned from a (sub)query, add a [LIMIT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset). But this is not needed here because in SQLite, scalar subqueries have an implicit LIMIT 1.

Column values from `a` are not available inside `InvoiceRevised` because that is an independent table. You have to replace the outer join with correlated subqueries, one for each column:

```
SELECT id,
       CodeValue,
       TotalAmount,
       (SELECT Id
        FROM Invoices
        JOIN SCSInvoiceRels ON Invoices.Id = SCSInvoiceRels.InvoiceId
        WHERE SCSInvoiceRels.RecordStatus = 1
          AND Invoices.RecordStatus = 1
          AND SCSInvoiceRels.SCDetailId IN (SELECT SCDetailId
                                            FROM SCSInvoiceRels
                                            WHERE InvoiceId = a.id)
       ) AS RevisedInvoiceId,
       (SELECT /* there is no BillNumber in your InvoiceRevised ??? */
        FROM Invoices
        JOIN SCSInvoiceRels ON Invoices.Id = SCSInvoiceRels.InvoiceId
        WHERE SCSInvoiceRels.RecordStatus = 1
          AND Invoices.RecordStatus = 1
          AND SCSInvoiceRels.SCDetailId IN (SELECT SCDetailId
                                            FROM SCSInvoiceRels
                                            WHERE InvoiceId = a.id)
       ) AS RevisedInvoice,
       (SELECT pr.CodeValue
        FROM PatientRegs AS pr
        JOIN Patients AS pa ON pa.id = pr.PatientId
        JOIN SCDetails AS SC ON pr.id = SC.RegId
        JOIN SCSInvoiceRels AS SCb ON SC.id = SCb.SCDetailId
        WHERE SCb.InvoiceId = a.Id
       ) AS RegistrationNumber,
       (SELECT pa.Name
        FROM PatientRegs AS pr
        JOIN Patients AS pa ON pa.id = pr.PatientId
        JOIN SCDetails AS SC ON pr.id = SC.RegId
        JOIN SCSInvoiceRels AS SCb ON SC.id = SCb.SCDetailId
        WHERE SCb.InvoiceId = a.Id
       ) AS PatientName
FROM Invoices AS a
WHERE RecordStatus = 0
  AND UpdateOn IS NOT NULL
```